# What's the safest way to save password for web scraping using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape a website that needs login.  The code snippet below works by saving username and password in a config JSON file.  If someone gets access to the config file, the login information will be leaked out.  Is there a better way to enhance security, say encrypting the username and password?  Thanks in advance!

```
await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/", { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
await page.type("#email", config.username, { delay: 30 });
await page.type("#pass", config.password, { delay: 30 });
```

Comment: This depends entirely on your deployment environment. If you're in AWS for example, put the password in the parameter store.

Answer (score -1):

By the very fact you store the password locally and send it out later means that you either assume the machine it is being done on is "100% secure" (or secure enough, for your purposes), or that you don't care much about that password. Encrypting the config file will only work if you encrypt it using something isn't stored on that machine, but then you'll have to provide that something every time you run that script.

You can, obviously, obfuscate it one way or another, but it will NEVER be secure.

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1: JWT**

You can use something like [Json Web Token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to encrypt data (And store it). The "problem" with JWT is you need a token to encrypt/decrypt the data and that token have to be in a safe location (You mind, maybe). So, everytime you start the server, you need to give it the token.

```js
// Encrypt
let data = {username: 'ciro-gomes', password: 'Dá bilhão?'};
var encrypted = jwt.sign(data, 'my random token');
// Store encrypted data
```

```js
// Decrypt
var data = jwt.verify(encrypted, 'my random token');
// data = {username: 'ciro-gomes', password: 'Dá bilhão?'}
```

---

**Option 2: Use tokens provided by the website**

Normally, after login, the website gives you some cookies which are used to authenticate the user during the next access (Without asking for password). You should store these cookies and, when needed, restore them to Puppeteer.
Of curse someone could use this data to access the website, but it is an website's issue. Normally, when the user try to access important stuff, the website ask the password to be safe.

Comment: I like the cookie option.  Thanks for answering the question.

Comment: But for 2nd option, you still have to login at least once right? Do you mean that we should login manually?

Comment: Caution: JWT does **not** encrypt and decrypt data. It is extremely trivial to decode JWT to reveal the plaintext. JWT merely hashes the data as a way of proving that the data is trusted/untampered with. Use real encryption if the intend is to secure the data.